# Get values from list MongoDB java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

now i have collection with documents like this:

```
 {
    "_id": ObjectId("585a8ccc85a4ab1b160b39dc"),
    "name": "GuildName",
    "slots": 100,
    "members": [{
        "membername": "playername1",
        "rank": 3
    }, {
        "membername": "playername1",
        "rank": 5
    }],
    "purchases": [],
 }
```

I need to get a list of members from "members" to put it in HashMap(String, Integer). (as key - value of "membername", as Integer - value of "rank").

Comment: Add the code that you have tried so far and someone can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `doc` is the `Document` object containing your document:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> memberMap = new HashMap<>();
List<Document> members = (List<Document>)doc.get("members");
for (Document member : members) {
    memberMap.put(
            (String)member.get("membername"),
            (Integer)member.get("rank"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this. based on what is your approach.

if you are using `BasicBSONObject`  then

> You can call `toMap()` function on `BasicBSONObject` which returns
>   `LinkedHashMap<String,Object>`

if you are using document object then i am not sure why you want to explicitly convert it to another hashmap because the `org.bson.Document` by default `implements Map<String,Object>` so you can perform all the operations on document object directly which you do on a hashmap.

if you still want to copy it to another hashmap you can use Yoshiya's code.